How g++ -O3 flag optimize for loop?
I use the following code to test the time consumed.
main.c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <random>

#define N 1000
#define DIM 1000
#define NS_PER_SECOND 1000000000

void sub_timespec(struct timespec t1, struct timespec t2, struct timespec *td)
{
    td->tv_nsec = t2.tv_nsec - t1.tv_nsec;
    td->tv_sec = t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec;
    if (td->tv_sec > 0 && td->tv_nsec < 0)
    {
        td->tv_nsec += NS_PER_SECOND;
        td->tv_sec--;
    }
    else if (td->tv_sec < 0 && td->tv_nsec > 0)
    {
        td->tv_nsec -= NS_PER_SECOND;
        td->tv_sec++;
    }
}

float cal_data_sqrtf(float *data, int data_length) {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data_length; i++) {
        sum += data[i] * data[i];
    }
    return sqrtf(sum);
}

int main() {
    float db_feat[N][DIM];
    float db_feat_norm[N];
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
            db_feat[j][i] = rand()/float(RANDMAX);
        }
        db_feat_norm[j] = cal_data_sqrtf(db_feat[j], DIM);
    }
    float features[DIM];
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        features[i] = rand()/float(RANDMAX);
    }
    float features_norm = cal_data_sqrtf(features, DIM);

    int runtime = 10;
    struct timespec start, end, delta;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    float view_sim[N];
    for (int k = 0; k < runtime; k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            float sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                sum += db_feat[j][i] * features[i];
            }
            if (sum < 0)
                sum = 0;
            view_sim[j] = sum / (db_feat_norm[j] * features_norm);
        }
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
    sub_timespec(start, end, &delta);
    printf("running time: %d.%.9ld\n", (int)delta.tv_sec, delta.tv_nsec);
}

If main.c is compiled by
g++ -std=c++11 -o main main.c
The running time is proportional to the runtime.
However, if main.c is compiled with -O3 flag:
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -o main main.c
The running time is extremely short (0.000000128) even with a large runtime=1000000.
The running time should increase as runtime increases.
What does -O3 do to the for loop?

The whole loop can be optimized away as none of the results are used in a way that affects observable behavior. You never print the result, or write it to a file, or consume it in any observable way.

If you want to benchmark something, either take the time to learn about all the common caveats, or use an existing benchmarking framework. Hand-rolling your own benchmark without the necessary knowledege rarely ends well. This is especially true for C and C++. On the other hand, if you are just interested in optimization techniques, you can always see the generated assembly yourself.

Side note: Compiling C code with a C++ compiler can sometimes trip fatally over one of the many difference between the two languages. But that's if you are fortunate. Tripping over one of those differences during the inquest into why the plane crashed... That really sucks.

You've written some code that does nothing except consume time. Consuming time is (obviously) not preserved by optimization.
